# How to extract column names from dataframe and compare it to input

Tags: r, shiny

I have set textInput for entering the column name which needs to be considered for operation. I want to compare it to an existing column having the same name in the dataframe to process on elements under the column.

Comment: Please provide the code that you already have, preferably minimized to a simple sample which can be considered a general example for R. State the expected behavior and how your code deviates from the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
#make some data
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c("a","b","c")
#put it in a dataframe
df <- data.frame(x,y)

#put the name of a column in a variable and access the column
textInput <- "x"
df[textInput]
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
#put the name of a column in a variable and access the column
textInput <- "y"
df[textInput]
  y
1 a
2 b
3 c
```